# Why glGetSubroutineIndex returns the same value for different function?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, subroutine

I have got a fragment shader that should operate 2 colors - red and blue.

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

subroutine vec4 colorRedBlue();

subroutine (colorRedBlue) 
vec4 redColor() 
{
    return vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
} 

subroutine (colorRedBlue) 
vec4 blueColor() 
{ 
    return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

subroutine uniform colorRedBlue myRedBlueSelection;

void main()
{
    outColor = myRedBlueSelection();
}
```

when I cout `glGetSubroutineIndex(shaderProgram, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "redColor");` and  `glGetSubroutineIndex(shaderProgram, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "blueColor");`

they are the same numbers: `4294967295`

Why they are the same numbers? What did I do wrong?

Comment: 4294967295 is 0xffffffff, which is `GL_INVALID_INDEX`.

Comment: `If name is not the name of a subroutine uniform in the shader stage, GL_INVALID_INDEX is returned`, but `name` is the name of a subroutine for sure, I think.

Comment: Hmmm... I see, but the guy here: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/subroutines/ has written that `name` should be a function name and `glGetSubroutineUniformLocation` should take a uniform name, and that make sense, because they take the same parameters. Same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498767/multiple-subroutine-types-defined-in-the-same-fragment-shader-does-not-work-corr here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve information about the subroutine indices the you have to use [`glGetActiveSubroutineUniformiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetActiveSubroutineUniform.xhtml):

```
GLint no_of_subroutines;
glGetActiveSubroutineUniformiv(
    shaderProgram, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 
    0, // Index of the subroutine uniform, but NOT the location of the uniform variable 
    GL_NUM_COMPATIBLE_SUBROUTINES, &no_of_subroutines);

std::vector<GLint> sub_routines( no_of_subroutines ); 
glGetActiveSubroutineUniformiv(
    shaderProgram, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 
    0, // Index of the subroutine uniform, but NOT the location of the uniform variable 
    GL_COMPATIBLE_SUBROUTINES, sub_routines.data());
```

The name of a subroutine which corresponds to a subroutine index can be get by [`glGetActiveSubroutineName`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetActiveSubroutineName.xhtml).

But I recommend to use layout qualifier to specify the subroutine indices in the shader code - see [Shader Subroutine - In-shader specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Subroutine#In-shader_specification):

```
subroutine vec4 colorRedBlue();

layout(index = 1) subroutine (colorRedBlue) 
vec4 redColor() 
{
    return vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
} 

layout(index = 2) subroutine (colorRedBlue) 
vec4 blueColor() 
{ 
    return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}  

layout(location = 0) subroutine uniform colorRedBlue myRedBlueSelection;
```

Note, all the subroutines for all the subroutine unifroms of one shader stage have to be set at once, by [`glUniformSubroutinesuiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniformSubroutines.xhtml). In your case, that's not a big thing, because there is only 1 subroutine uniform. This operation applies to the current shader program (`glUsePrgram`).
The number of indices wich you have to pass to `glUniformSubroutinesuiv` has to match the number of `GL_ACTIVE_SUBROUTINE_UNIFORM_LOCATIONS` but not the number of `GL_ACTIVE_SUBROUTINE_UNIFORM` - see [`glGetProgramStageiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramStage.xhtml):

```
GLint nLocationCount = 0;
glGetProgramStageiv( 
    program, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_ACTIVE_SUBROUTINE_UNIFORM_LOCATIONS, &nLocationCount );

std::vector<GLuint> sub_routines( nLocationCount, 0 );

Glint redBlueSelection_location = 0;
sub_routines[redBlueSelection_location] = 1; // index of 'redColor` or `blueColor`

glUniformSubroutinesuiv(
    GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, (GLsizei)sub_routines.size(), sub_routines.data() );
```